# Pass Express function to another file which calls HTTPS createServer

Tags: node.js, express

According to [Node Best Practices](https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices/blob/master/sections/projectstructre/separateexpress.md), it's recommended to separate the HTTP and Express server API.

My issue is that `createServer` expects a function as the second argument but I am passing in an object.

**app.js**

```
const config = require('./config');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + config.STATIC_DIR));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// POST /agent used for registration requests
app.post('/agent', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Received registration request from ', req.body);
  return res.send('Received a POST HTTP method');
});
```

**server.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./config');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const app = require('./app');

const sslConfig = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(config.SSL_KEY),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(config.SSL_CERT)
};

const server = require('https').createServer(sslConfig, app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

I get the following error:

```
 throw new errors.ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type Function. Received type object
    at checkListener (events.js:55:11)
    at _addListener (events.js:214:3)
    at Server.addListener (events.js:272:10)
    at new Server (https.js:67:10)
    at Object.createServer (https.js:85:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Code/server.js:18:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
```

What changes are required if I want to pass an SSL configuration into the `createServer` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by adding the following line at the end of `app.js`:

```
module.exports = app;
```